# Get data from api, and display it in html

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have an API file that looks like this:
[image: Take a look (Image)]

I want to get info from this api and display it in html page to look like this
[image]

I've searched forum but can't find anything good for me. 
If anyone could help that would be awesome! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You must parse the json code to an array in php:

```
$array = json_decode($json_data,true);
```

Then you can print it out like this:

```
echo $array["bonusValues"];
```

This are for the first level keys. When you have a second level key you must use the following:

```
echo $array["first"]["second"];
```

And if you have an array in json:

```
echo $array["first"][0]["item_name"];
```

So the 0 in the middle stands for increment value of an element.

To fetch the data from an url you can use the file_get_contents function:

```
$json_data = file_get_contents("http://www.your-url.com/");
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should download html file. I recomend using CURL.
Next decode your data from json to php array

```
$array = json_decode($data, true);
```

To use CURL

```
url_setopt_array($ch, array(
     CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
     CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
     CURLOPT_URL => "url",
     CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query(array(
     "POST FIELD" => $value,
     ))
    ));
$data = curl_exec($ch);
```

And then use echo function for $array elements

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery **$.ajax** and JSON.stringify to show content of JSON in nice way in browser.

Like this:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: '/my/api/endpoint',
   data: 'var1=value&var2=value2',
   success: function(response) {
      var data = JSON.parse(response);
      var mydata1 = data.lastTransactions;

      $("#myHtmlBox").html(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2));
   }
});
```

example of using $.ajax here: [jQuery Ajax POST example with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php)

or by using PHP:

```
$json = json_encode(file_get_contents("http://www.myapi.com/"));
$data = $json->lastTransactions;
echo json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

also use tags: `<pre></pre>` what will print out nice and formated JSON.